# what's the difference between .id and .attr('id') in jquery

Tags: jquery, element, this, identity, attr

```
var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
```

`x.id` gives me `undefined` while `x.attr('id')` returns the correct id.

Can anyone tell me the difference between those two.
btw, is there a better way to get `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()`, I don't want to assign ids to them since this would make it harder to work with those elements.

Thanks

Comment: That's some hardcore relative DOM traversal, sir.

Comment: Using IDs will actually make it easier to work with elements.... Not harder!

Comment: @c0deNinja I have a lot of x. In this case, I got to assign ids to all of its children, and construct id string from this.id, which is pretty boring.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`x.id` works when `x` is a DOM element, not when `x` is a jQuery object.

If `x` is a jQuery object, you can either do:

```
x[0].id
```

to get the first DOM element from the jQuery object or you can use:

```
x.attr('id')
```

to use the jQuery method for retrieving an attribute.

As for your other question, the better way to replace this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

is to put a class on the desired parent and use this:

```
$(this).closest(".target")
```

The `.closest(selector)` method will find the nearest parent that matches the selector.  Using a class to solve this issue makes it easy to design since you don't have to use unique IDs.

Answer (score 3):

.id is a property of the dom element whereas your code is fetching a jquery object. See this example. Oh, and note that if you are in jQuery 1.7+ you probably want to be using `prop` and not `attr`

```
$('#foo').prop('id'); //foo
$('#foo').id;         //undefined
$('#foo').get(0).id;  //foo
```

If possible, I would try and define classes to represent your quadruple parent element. Then you could do something like

```
$(this).parents('.class');
```

Note the use of parents with an 's'

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

can be written as:

```
$(this).parents().eq(3)
```

or:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(3)')
```